# How to convert Date from Mongoose to a different format

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am storing some values to `MongoDB` using `mongoose` and one thing I am disappointed about is the format of the `date` retrieving from the `MongoDB` database.

This is what I am getting:

`2019-10-03T00:00:00.000Z`

How can I convert this to: **10/03/2019**

Answer (score 0):

You can convert date to any format using momentjs library. More details: https://momentjs.com/docs/
You can also use built in toLocaleString javascript function. Details: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-date-tolocalestring/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```js
    let enterDate = '2019-10-03T00:00:00.000Z'
    let date = new Date(enterDate);  // enterDate you get from mongoose

    let day = date.getDate();
    let month = date.getMonth()+1;
    let year = date.getFullYear();

    console.log(month+"/"+day+"/"+year

)
```